# Z score in Mann Whitney U

Tags: spss, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, z-score

So in SPSS I did a mann-whitney u test.

There is significant difference between the median ranks - p score below 0.5

But, it also provided a Z score along with a W and U score.

What is the z score for and what can i do with it?

Comment: The Mann-Whitney doesn't compare median ranks.

Answer (score 1):

The [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test) is quite thorough in the calculations involved with the Mann-Whitney U test.

SPSS is using a [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mann%E2%80%93Whitney_U_test#Normal_approximation_and_tie_correction) to the Mann-Whitney U statistic to obtain a $p$-value. The z-score given is compared to the standard normal quantiles to obtain a $p$-value.

Comment: Thanks. So is the z score needed in the analysis?

Comment: What do you mean by "needed"?